# trying to understand better the orm methods but i can store a value in a field

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8

I want to store a field's value 'por_sucursal' from res_users class in a field 'probando' from pruebas the value its boolean and i can store it i need it for a filter in xml file.

```
class pruebas(osv.Model):
    _name = 'pruebas'
    _description = 'Sucursales de la empresa'  


def dame_usuario2(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names=None, arg=False, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    var_pool = self.pool.get('res_users')
    if var_pool:
        ids = var_pool.search(cr, uid, [('id','=',uid)])
        if ids:
            return ids[0].por_sucursal


_columns = {            
        'name': fields.char('prueba', size=50, help="Probando"),
        'probando': fields.function(dame_usuario2, type='boolean', store=True,
                                            readonly = True),
            }
pruebas()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
class pruebas(osv.Model):
    _name = 'pruebas'
    _description = 'Sucursales de la empresa'  


    def dame_usuario2(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names=None, arg=False, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        var_pool = self.pool.get('res.users')
        res = {}
        for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res[obj.id] = False
            user = var_pool.browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
            if user:
                res[obj.id] = user.por_sucursal
        return res

    _columns = {            
            'name': fields.char('prueba', size=50, help="Probando"),
            'probando': fields.function(dame_usuario2, type='boolean', store=True, readonly = True),
                }
pruebas()
```

Comment: it doesnt record nothing all values are Null or empty

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'browse' it came with this error

Comment: See I have updated the answer, it's because wrong model name written in `self.pool.get('res_users') ` actually model is `res.users`.

Comment: no doesnt record nothng when i print the variable its empty, why? i try all methods, sql, this, i miss the simple search, read in the data base

Comment: Ohh! yes when you run first time calculating fields.function if you get any error it doesn't calculating another time, so you just need to do one thing comment this field in _columns and restart server then update modules and again make it uncomment and then restart server and update module. it will done surely.

Comment: For confirmation you should try with new record not with existing one, create new record and check that whether it works or not.

Comment: i always do what you say in your first comment, thanks for it, but the thing is that the record its empty brand new, so it works perfectly but when i change the principal field "por sucursal" that it is boolean if it was false i changed it into True, nothing happens with the field "probando" still being False, im trying to do now like a clean all records before the process  but im still trying althougth we can only record one time into the field with a function how we can do it each time we view data on a tree view

Comment: Remove `store=True` from the field definition, then it will call this function each time you access this field.

Comment: i did that but in the XML file doesnt reconigze the field to filter my view look i have my service's orders from many sucursals (means many cities) i want to list all orders from the logged (active) user's sucursal that why i nedd the field to compare and it does it but only one time and if i remove store with false doesnt reconize the field in the domain filter

Comment: Could you please share your res.users model if you have extended it, you can do it with by setting up watch on fields.function.

Comment: class res_users(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.users'  
    
    _columns = {            
                'por_sucursal': fields.boolean('Por Sucursal', help="Es por Sucursal"),

Comment: 'sucursal_u' : fields.many2one('sucursales', 'Sucursal', help="Selecciona la sucursal"),           
                'tecnichian': fields.boolean('Tecnico', help="Es de servicio"),
                'sup_monitoreo': fields.boolean('Supervisar monitoreo', help="Es supervisora de monitoreo"),
                }

Comment: _defaults = {
                 'tecnichian': False,
                 'sup_monitoreo' :False,
                 'por_sucursal': False,
                 'sucursal_u' : 0,
                                  }

Comment: i post all again much better here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720025/can-we-compare-in-a-domain-2-fileds-from-the-same-class-and-one-its-not-stored

Answer (score 0):

Signature for functional field is:

```
fnct: function to compute the field value (required)

    def fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context)
        returns a dictionary { ids→values } with values of type=type
```

Look at the return type of the method, `dictionary { ids→values }`. You need to return a dictionary of dictionary like `{ids: {'key':'value'}}` i.e `key -> field name`.

```
class pruebas(osv.Model):
    _name = 'pruebas'
    _description = 'Sucursales de la empresa'  

    def dame_usuario2(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names=None, arg=False, context=None):
        result = {}
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        var_pool = self.pool.get('res.users')
        for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            value = {}
            user = var_pool.browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
            if user:
                value['probando'] = user.por_sucursal
                result[obj.id] = value
        return result

    _columns = {            
            'name': fields.char('prueba', size=50, help="Probando"),
            'probando': fields.function(dame_usuario2, type='boolean', store=True, readonly = True),
                }
pruebas()
```

Comment: this didnt work it doesnt give me an error but it doesnt store the correct value it recods or stores False when the value its True, i am going to try the up answer thanks anyway i am really greatful for your help

Comment: you know i get into the data base and i delete the field probando and i ran odoo again and it records the information but if i change the value doesnt change it keeps the first value so how i can delete all records from the field each time before i redord the field ?